# How many times does the Django ORM hit the database when calling a foreign key's primary key and using the in list filter?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Lets say I have the following models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

Now, I am doing the following queries:

```
foo_pks = set([])
for bar in Bar.objects.filter(name='some_name'):
    foo_pks.add(bar.foo.pk)

for foo in Foo.objects.filter(pk__in=foo_pks):
    # Do something
```

So basically, I am adding the primary keys to the set, and then using that set to make another query. How many times am I hitting the database? Moreover, is this horribly inefficient, and if so, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) out.

Comment: You're hitting the database a lot. There is so much written about this, both in the docs and on SO.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#in

Comment: The fastest method would be `__in` with an inner queryset. Look for `inner_qs` in those links.